# While using react-toolbox webpack is giving an error elements.loader.split is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Here is my Webpack.config.js.It is working fine in some other project but when i copied same configuration in this project it gave me above error.After doing some research i found that **loader** takes **string** as inputs and **loaders** takes **arrays** as inputs and that should be an issue but i don't think i have that issue in my code.Please gude

```
    const postcssPlugins = [
  require('postcss-cssnext')(),
  require('postcss-modules-values')
];

const scssLoader = [
  { loader: 'style-loader' },
  { loader: 'css-loader' },
  { loader: 'sass-loader' }
];

const postcssLoader = [
  { loader: 'style-loader' },
  { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } },
  { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { plugins: () => [...postcssPlugins] } }
];

var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
          entry: './src/main/resources/static/js/app.js',
          output: {
            path: __dirname + '/src/main/resources/static/js', 
            filename: 'bundle.js' 
          },
  module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         },
         {
             test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
             loader: scssLoader,
             include: [__dirname]
           },
           { test: /\.css$/,
             loader: postcssLoader,
             include: [__dirname]
           }
      ]

   }
};
```

Comment: What is the webpack version you are running? Your config seems to be pre 2.x

Comment: how to check the webpack version?Anyways i installed webpack again and it worked fine after that no idea how

Comment: Package.json :)

Comment: haha sorry!its 2.3.3

Comment: So, your config is probably not compliant with webpack 2x